# Efficiently extract numbers from a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a column in pandas dataframe as below:

```
     Manufacture_Id  Score  Rank
0             S1     93     1
1             S1     91     2
2             S1     86     3
3             S2     88     1
4            S25     73     2
5           S100     72     3
6           S100     34     1
7           S100     24     2
```

I want to extract the ending numbers from the '**Manufacture_Id**' column into a new column as below:

```
   Manufacture_Id  Score  Rank   Id
0             S1     93     1    1
1             S1     91     2    1
2             S1     86     3    1
3             S2     88     1    2
4            S25     73     2   25
5           S100     72     3  100
6           S100     34     1  100
7           S100     24     2  100
```

I have written the below code which gives the results but it is not efficient when the data becomes big.

```
test['id'] = test.Manufacture_Id.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)')
```

Is there a way to do it efficiently?

Data:

```
#Ceate dataframe
data = [
    ["S1",93,1],
    ["S1",91,2],
    ["S1",86,3],
    ["S2",88,1],
    ["S25",73,2],
    ["S100",72,3],
    ["S100",34,1],
    ["S100",24,2],
       
]

#dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Manufacture_Id', 'Score', 'Rank'])
```

Comment: Can you try `test["id"] = test.Manufacture_Id.str.extract(r"([\d.]+)$")` ?

Comment: `test["id"] = test.Manufacture_Id.str[1:].astype(int)`

Comment: Is it always `S` followed by numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be more efficient than regex.

```
test["id"] = test['Manufacture_Id'].str[1:].astype(int)
```

But if the `S` is not constant then you try following snippet.

```
test["id"] = test.Manufacture_Id.str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Comment: did you just post my comment as an answer?

Comment: We aren't told that `Manufacture_Id` is always one nonnumerical character followed by numerical characters, only that it ends in numerical characters. For all we know, `ABC123` could be an id.

Comment: Sorry @Marat, I didn't check that

Comment: I update my answer, It will handle your mentioned issue @Blake

Comment: Check the regex of OP: `(\d+\.\d+|\d+)`. Your code should fail for `ABC12.3`

Comment: If I am guessing correct the `Manufacture_Id` shouldn't be fractional. But if I consider your point then your pattern is correct. @Corralien